# automatically separate mm:ss in editText?

Tags: java, android

I would like the user to input a time in minutes and seconds. How do I automatically add in a ":" after the minutes have been input ?

Using Eclipse with Java.

So far I have this:

```
EditText editTextT;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

editTextT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextT);

editTextT.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (editTextT.getText().length() == 2) {
        editTextT.setText(editTextT.getText() + ":");
        editTextT.setSelection(editTextT.getText().length());
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: please edit your question and add the programming language you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add an `KeyListener` to your `TextField`. 
Then for example you can react to a key released. You check the text in your textarea for the length and just add a `:` to the end of the string.
Have a look at this:

```
textfield.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if (textfield.getText().length() == 2) {
                    textfield.setText(textfield.getText() + ":");
                    textfield.setCaretPosition(textfield.getText().length());
                }
            }
        });
```

**EDIT:**
This is the solution for Java like you mentioned above, if you need a solution for Android (because of your `editText`), try this:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (editText.getText().length() == 2) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText() + ":");
            editText.setSelection(et.getText().length());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {} 
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Please see the update and try it with a TextWatcher.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have implemented it but it seems to only be called when backspace/delete is hit. I.e. if 2 digits are entered, nothing happens, but if I enter 3 then delete one the colon is entered. I will copy and paste my new code into my original post

Comment: TextWatcher is giving an error "The type new TextWatcher(){} must implement the inherited abstract method TextWatcher.onTextChanged(CharSequence, int, int, int)"